# Title slide (first slide) and second slide are numbered one in my slideshow: sharelatex

Tags: beamer

For some reason, my title slide and the second slide are numbered one. After that, the slides are numbered correctly. Can anyone help me in numbering it correctly. Thank you for your time.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{utopia} %font utopia imported
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{default}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%codification of the document

\usepackage{comment}

\title{Spectral decomposition of a real symmetric matrix \\ by}
\author{asdfg
\\School of Computer Science
\\University
\\USA
}

\date{May 2018}

%Here begins the body of the document
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\end{titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Eigenvalue and eigenvector pair of a matrix}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Let \(A\in R^{n*n}\) be a real matrix of order n
    \item If there exist a scalar, \(\lambda(real/complex)\) and a vector,                  V(real/complex) such that 
        \\  \[A*V= \lambda*V-------->(1)\]\\ then \(\lambda\) is the eigen vector and V is the corresponding eigen vector of A
    \item The pair \((\lambda, V)\) satisfying (1) is called an eigen pair of A
    \item The set of all eigen values of A is called the spectrum of A
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a title page in beamer use

```
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
```

or `\maketitle`. Then the frames are also numbered correctly.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{utopia} %font utopia imported
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usecolortheme{default}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%codification of the document

\usepackage{comment}

\title[Spectral decomposition of a real symmetric matrix]{Spectral decomposition of a real symmetric matrix \\ by}
\author[asdfg]{asdfg
\\School of Computer Science
\\University
\\USA
}

\date{May 2018}

%Here begins the body of the document
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Eigenvalue and eigenvector pair of a matrix}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Let \(A\in R^{n*n}\) be a real matrix of order n
    \item If there exist a scalar, \(\lambda(real/complex)\) and a vector,                  V(real/complex) such that 
        \\  \[A*V= \lambda*V-------->(1)\]\\ then \(\lambda\) is the eigen vector and V is the corresponding eigen vector of A
    \item The pair \((\lambda, V)\) satisfying (1) is called an eigen pair of A
    \item The set of all eigen values of A is called the spectrum of A
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Off-topic:

- Putting formatting instructions inside macros like `\author` is not really a good idea, at least give an alternative short title which then will be used in the footline.
- please note that the `utopia` package is to be regarded as obsolete. (It does not have any effect anyway in its current usage)
- you don't need `\usecolortheme{default}`, as the name suggest, this theme is loaded per default

Comment: taking the QO code into test, I get two titlepages, no following slide and a lot of false page numbering. also a lot of warnings about deprecated packages.

Comment: @naphaneal Really? I get one title page and then the normal next slide. Which engine did you use? Which beamer version do you have? [I added a warning about the deprecate package]

Comment: I used `pdflatex` and `beamer` from the 2017 TL installation. also, `ragged2e`'s deprecated, too. taking your code example, gives me the expected output. Whiskey Tango Foxtrot?

Comment: @naphaneal I did not hear before about `ragged2e` being deprecated. How to get justified text without it? I just tested with TL2017 and it works just fine for me.

Comment: sorry, my bad. `ragged2e` is still liable. misread the warnings. but the QO code still malfunctions for me. this is strange. the code you posted: within expected parameters. even stranger.

Comment: yeah, I found my error. I forgot about `titleframe`. all is well.